# Two color conditional formatting centered around a number in excel 365

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-365

I am trying to set up a two color conditional scale where the highest is green, the lowest is red, and where it flips from green at a reference cell.  So for example.

| Target | Ex1 | Ex2 | Ex3 | Ex4 | Ex5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .5 | .4 | .2 | .6 | .1 | .9 |

I would like Ex 1 to be light red, Ex 2 to be medium red, and Ex4 to be dark red.  And I would like Ex3 to be light green and Ex5 to be dark green.

Three color formatting will not work as it will result in Ex1 and Ex3 being not red or green and I need all to be either red or green.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: CF rule takes max and min value by default and distributes the color based on that. If your data got high variance, you cannot control the colors so much. Maybe with a 3 color scale and playing with percentiles you could do it but it's more a try/error question than a documented one. As example. Ex2 and ·x4 values are closer between them than Ex2 and Ex1 so color between Ex2 and Ex4 will be more similar than between Ex1 and Ex2

Comment: Can you not just set up 5 individual rules for each of the colours? It it simply the Highest value Dark green, down to the lowest value being dark red or are there values associated with the colour bandings

Answer (score 1):

There is the three-color scale, as shown in this screenshot. The value in the middle refers to the value 2 you can see in that one cell:

[image]

Comment: From my original post: "Three color formatting will not work as it will result in Ex1 and Ex3 being not red or green and I need all to be either red or green."